# Dozent möchte geduzt werden

Tags: address, written-language

Ich studiere in Deutschland und mein Betreuer hat mir gesagt, dass wir uns duzen können.
Jetzt muss ich ihm eine E-mail schreiben. Wie sollte die Anrede am besten aussehen?
Lieber Professor < Nachname >? Oder nur Lieber < Vorname >?

Er fängt immer seine E-mails mit Lieber < mein Vorname > an.

Comment: *Duzen* hat nicht automatisch zur Folge, dass man die Korrespondenz mit *Lieber ...* anfangen sollte, denn das würde man nur unter Vertrauten verwenden, also zum Beispiel, wenn man in derselben Arbeitsgruppe zusammenarbeitet. Ansonsten ist *Hallo ...* oder *Guten Tag ...* die angemessene Anrede.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich, das mag langsam altmodisch werden, aber "Lieber" kann durchaus auch förmlichen Charakter haben. Auf jeden Fall mehr als "Hallo".

Comment: @CarstenS Im akademischen Umfeld, habe ich den Eindruck, wird die förmliche Variante gerade sogar wieder modern, gerade unter jüngeren Dozierenden.

Comment: Ich denke, ein "Hallo <Vorname>" passt in dem Fall am besten. Ich hatte auch schon solche Professoren und in meinem momentanen Berufsumfeld machen wir das eigentlich immer so.

Comment: Alles klar, danke

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Duzen und die Verwendung des Vornamens gehen — mit sehr wenigen Ausnahmen — miteinander einher (*).

Wenn ein Dozent das Du angeboten hat, erfolgt die Kommunikation danach mit dem Vornamen.

Bezüglich der Anrede gibt es eine ganze Fülle von Dingen. Wenn der Dozent eh "Lieber " verwendet, dann kannst du da nichts mit falsch machen.

Den Nachnamen zu verwenden, wenn dein gegenüber den Vornamen verwendet und das Du angeboten hat wirkt sehr merkwürdig und distanziert, fast wie eine latente Ablehnung des Du. Ich würde dies nicht empfehlen.

<sub>(*) In der Oberstufe wird manchmal von Lehren die Kombination von Vorname und "Sie" verwendet.</sub>

Comment: Bekannt als Ausnahme sind vor allem das [Hamburger-Sie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_Sie) und das Kassiererinnen-Du

Comment: Die Kombination Lieber <Vorname> ist meiner Erfahrung nach im akademischen Kontext üblich. Das sollte natürlich immer vom Dozenten ausgehen.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn er "Lieber " benutzt, kannst Du das auch tun. Ihr seid beide erwachsen, so dass die Anrede symmetrisch sein sollte.

Comment: Ok, aber ist es besser Lieber <sein Vorname> oder Lieber  Professor <sein Nachname>? Ich würde die zweite Möglichkeit wählen..Lieber Stefan klingelt zu informell...

Comment: Wenn er ausdrücklich gesagt hat, dass ihr euch duzen könnt und er Deinen Vornamen benutzt, würde ich auch den Vornamen benutzen.

Comment: @RubenCamposDelgado Auf keinen Fall "Professor + Nachname", wenn er das *Du* angeboten hat! Vielleicht kommen manche deutsche Gepflogenheiten als "kleiner Kulturschock" daher, aber man sollte es so akzeptieren wie es ist.Und gerade an den Universitäten ist das *Sie* stark auf dem Rückzug. Die Verwendung des *Sie* nach angebotenem *Du* könnte sogar als Affront augefasst werden. Hier eine (altmodische) Faustregel: Höhergestellte oder deutlich ältere Personen niemals von sich aus duzen, sondern abwarten, welche Anrede sie verwenden und dann  "symmetrisch" reagieren.

Comment: Falls aber "Lieber Stephan" für Sie / Dich einen zu intimen Klang hat, kann in E-Mails genauso gut "Hallo Stephan" oder "Guten Tag Stephan" benutzt werden. Das braucht nicht symmetrisch zu sein. Das sagt mir meine langjährige berufliche Erfahrung in einem deutlich konservativeren Umfeld.